# Retornar dados de 01 coluna em 03

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou trabalhando com uns dados em uma tabela, na qual fiz um SELECT que uma das colunas retorna o status dos processos que estão em andamento na nossa fila. Os dados desta coluna são por exemplo: "Em andamento", "Concluído", "Cancelado".

Eu preciso dividir estes retornos em 03 colunas, de modo que:

```
Coluna 01 retorne: "Em andamento" 
Coluna 02 retorne: "Concluído"
Coluna 03: "Cancelado"
```

Estou utilizando SQL Server.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observem que na coluna Status tenho 04 tipos de retornos diferentes. Eu gostaria de exibir cada retorno que fosse diferente, em uma coluna específica, como se houvesse mais 04 colunas: Status 01, Status 02, Status 03 e Status 04.

Status 01 exibe: Rascunho;
Status 02 exibe: Aguardando correção;
Status 03 exibe: Preencher próxima etapa;
Status 04 exibe: Aguardando correção;

Comment: Não me ficou claro o retorno que deseja, poderia adicionar na pergunta 1 exemplo de como deseja os dados.

Comment: Você quer que nas linhas de cada status retorne os processos que possuem aquele status Ou seria um computador tador de quantos processos tem cada status?

Comment: Mostre a estrutura da tabela com alguns dados de exemplo. Se possível, crie um fiddle aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma sugestão é o uso do CASE:

```
create table tblTeste
(
  ID int,
  ID_STATUS int
)

create table tblStatus
(
    ID_STATUS int,
    STATUS varchar(50)
)

insert into tblTeste (ID, ID_STATUS) values (1, 1)
insert into tblTeste (ID, ID_STATUS) values (2, 1)
insert into tblTeste (ID, ID_STATUS) values (3, 2)
insert into tblTeste (ID, ID_STATUS) values (4, 2)
insert into tblTeste (ID, ID_STATUS) values (5, 3)
insert into tblTeste (ID, ID_STATUS) values (6, 3)
insert into tblTeste (ID, ID_STATUS) values (7, 4)
insert into tblTeste (ID, ID_STATUS) values (8, 4)

insert into tblStatus (ID_STATUS, STATUS) values (1, 'Rascunho')
insert into tblStatus (ID_STATUS, STATUS) values (2, 'Aguardando correção')
insert into tblStatus (ID_STATUS, STATUS) values (3, 'Preencher próxima etapa')
insert into tblStatus (ID_STATUS, STATUS) values (4, 'Aguardando correção')

select t.*,
    case when t.ID_STATUS = 1 then STATUS else '' end 'Status 1',
    case when t.ID_STATUS = 2 then STATUS else '' end 'Status 2',
    case when t.ID_STATUS = 3 then STATUS else '' end 'Status 3',
    case when t.ID_STATUS = 4 then STATUS else '' end 'Status 4'
from tblTeste t
inner join tblStatus s on s.ID_STATUS = t.ID_STATUS
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d36ac/1